# Is there a way to take 10 in Iaijutsu Focus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

I want to know if there is a way to take 10 while in combat for a specific skill (In this case Iaijutsu Focus).

I heard that there is a feat that allows you to do that but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feat Hardened Criminal, from City of Stormreach (page 95), grants the creature immunity to attempts to Intimidate it and the ability to take 10 under any circumstances on a single skill, chosen when the feat is chosen.

Comment: The only viable alternative feat is Ancestral Whispers (*Faiths of Eberron* 145), which takes a standard action to activate, is limited in uses per day by the possessor's turn undead attempts, only lasts a few rounds, and requires worshiping the Undying Court (therefore typically the feat's the province of—*brr*—elves), but, hey, it also grants a +4 bonus on those checks.

Comment: @HeyICanChan [blinks] How did the word "viable" make it in there? :P

Comment: O, it's not meant as a synonym for [*good*](https://www.google.com/search?q=viable%20definition&rct=j). `:-)`

Comment: You can even take the prerequisite feat as a warblade bonus feat! Tasty.

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho There's also the Otyugh Hole, if you *really* don't want to waste feats.

Answer (score 6):

Skill Mastery, a Rogue Special Ability in the Player's Handbook, lets you do this with 3+Int skills.  It's not worth taking, considering the other options, for most rogue builds, but you could take it and it would do this.  Being in the PHB this method will nearly always be theoretically available to you, whereas other methods of accomplishing this may not be.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a number of other classes (and prestige classes) allow picking from the Rogue Special Ability list, and therefore that Skill Mastery is not specifically tied to the Rogue class (although it still requires a Rogue-ish class).